# Just added mod_security... want to whitelist a series of sub directories

Tags: mod-security

I am running a host and just updated mod_security. It "broke" a CMS in multiple sites. I want to white list all sub-directories named CMS. How do I specify a rule to do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
SecRuleEngine Off
</Directory>
```

Comment: but this is just for a single directory... what if i want a bunch of directories that are named CMS?

like /path/to/CMS
/another/path/CMS
/yetanother/CMS

Comment: I don;t think regex are allowed in apache cfg files, though wildcard works; search in this direction

Comment: `<Directory>` and `<DirectoryMatch>` support regular expressions, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch

Answer (score 0):

See this wiki page for examples:

http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security